# What can i do with a stack in openslack

Tags: openstack

I am wondering what is a stack in openslack.
It seems to be components (network, containers and stuff)
Can i mix thoses items with docker containers for example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

OpenStack version of AWS cloudformation (infrastructure as a code) is performed trough HEAT (OpenStack Component). A "stack" is a set of resources that can be deployed in the cloud. What are those resources ?: Everything that can be created withing the cloud environment:
- A network port...
- A set of instances (virtual machines).
- A load balancer.
- A storage device (block or object).

Basically, you use a template (or a set of templates) in order to create a complete infrastructure inside the cloud (database servers, web servers, a load balancer for the web servers, maybe the storage too... etc.).

The template uses a common language to define those components and how are they created in the cloud.

Note that, many "AWS Cloudformation" objects can be defined in OpenStack HEAT templates, but, HEAT also has it's very own set of objects definitions for OpenStack.

At the end of my site you will find a sample HEAT template for a stack that include servers, loadbalancer and autoscalling:

https://tigerlinux.github.io/recipes/openstack/index.html

Also, more examples directly from the OpenStack community:

https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/heat-templates/tree/hot